# How to get results from Laravel concurrently method using Http get?

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle, swoole, octane

**Working:**

```
$users = Http::get('https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users');
$addresses = Http::get('https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/addresses');
echo($users['id']);
```

**Not Working:**

```
[$users, $addresses] = Octane::concurrently([
    fn () => Http::get('https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users'),
    fn () => Http::get('https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/addresses'),
]);
echo($users['id']);
```

**Error:**

```
fseek(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, int given
at vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php:211
```

**Versions**

```
- php -v
PHP 8.1.23 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2023 19:07:30) (NTS)
- php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 10.24.0
- php -i | grep swoole -1 | grep Version
Version => 5.1.0
```

`print_r($users)` gives back a full Illuminate\Http\Client\Response Object which has the entire GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object.
`$users->status()` gives back 200.  headers work as well.
However, `$users->body() and $users->json()` etc. give back the same error as above.

I can't find any documentation or any tutorial on how to handle multiple Http:get inside `Octane::concurrently`. Hope anyone can help me out with this, as I hoped this would be really simple to do so.

All I want to do for this proof of concept is to get back `$users['id']` after I did the Octane::concurrently method.